# Selecting 50 Words from a string

Tags: php, mysql, database

I have a string that contains over 1200 chars. I want to only select the first 50 words.

the string is `$row['message']`. I am confused between explode and substr.

Thanks.

Comment: one have to define "word" prior asking a question

Answer (score 5):

```
$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $row['message']);

$words = array_slice($words, 0, 50);
```

This code should do it.

Comment: preg_split is better than explode, because of the multiple spaces that may occur between words

Comment: or you can do it like this: `$words = preg_split('/\s+/', $row['message'], 50);`

Answer (score 2):

Try

```
$words = str_word_count($row['message'], 1);
$first50Words = array_slice($words, 0, 50);
```

Comment: Nice function! Please note that words may not contain special characters like `á` etcetera. You could add these characters to the third parameter though.

Answer (score 1):

```
function firstNwords($str,$n){
    return preg_replace('/((\b\w+\b.*?){'.$n.'}).*$/s','$1',$str);
}
```